# Column validation syntax in 2010

Tags: 2010, validation

I'm trying to find information on how to form proper column validation formulas, but can't find any explanation of formula syntax.

All I keep running into are snippets of formulas, what I'm looking for is a place that teaches me how to create my own.

Comment: So did you actually find a satisfactory answer?

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint validation uses formulas for calculated fields. Here's a page that shows how you can use functions in formulas: [SP2010 calculated field formulas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Comment: That list of formulas has a few problems in this context: First, it's not clear how to connect those formula examples of *manipulating* column contents into a formula for *validating* column contents. Second, not all possibilities seem to be present. I'm not able to figure out how to ensure that a column only contains a W followed by five or six numerals using the linked page.

Comment: @ToddWilcox, the _Column Validation_ in a column definition accepts a formula, which must evaluate to true for the value to be considered valid. In your case, you could use: AND(LEN([My Column])=6,LEFT([My Column],1)="W",TEXT(VALUE(RIGHT([My Column],5)),"00000")=RIGHT([My Column],5)). This checks for a "W" followed by 5 digits. Try also reading [this](http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2009/09/column-validation-in-sharepoint-2010/) and [this](http://thechriskent.com/tag/column-validation/)

Comment: The critical piece of information I eventually discovered is the it's an *Excel* formula. Lots of places say "just use a formula" which doesn't mean much without the word "Excel". With that knowledge, I just put a few fest rows into a worksheet and built an excel formula that evaluated the rows correctly and then copied and pasted that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The secret is the formulas are the exact same ones used in Excel. Make a spreadsheet with a column of test data, some valid and some not, and then built up logical formulas in a nearby column. You'll know you have the formula right when the formula column says "**TRUE**" for all the valid test data and anything else for invalid data. It doesn't have to say "**FALSE**" for invalid data, some of my invalids said "**#VALUE**" and my formula worked. Basically anything not TRUE counts as false. When you copy and paste the formula into sharepoint, omit the IF() function that you have to put around the whole thing in excel. You can use the excel help and trial and error to work out formula syntax.

Comment: i stumbled upon this thread after some (unfruitful) search on the net and when i realized were excel formulas i understood that the keywords are localized... beware you international users!

Answer (score -1):

Here is a page from [Microsoft's support site](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-IN/article/Examples-of-common-formulas-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3?ui=en-US&rs=en-IN&ad=IN) containing many examples of common formulas. It contains the following types of examples:

1. Conditional formulas
2. Date and time formulas
3. Mathematical formulas
4. Text formulas

Comment: do you know were i can see a list of all the formula functions? the MS site explains some things but leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: The above page has links to the available formula. 1) Conditional formulas 2) Date and time formulas 3) Mathematical formulas 4)Text formulas. What else you want?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions do you see how this site explains regexp? it breaks down the syntax and give examples, the MS site seems to only be examples and a slight explanation of said example. I'm looking for a site similar to the mozilla site